# Extract line in long list of data - binary

Tags: c++, substr

I have a file include different lines and the lines are starting by the some word and finish by (;).  i.e.

```
les enfant de la télé;
les efants sont  contants;
les enfants mangent bien, les enfants cherchent a se distraire;
```

I want to cut  this  sentences  and  arrange all as:

```
les enfant de la télé;
les efants sont  contants;
les enfants mangent bien;
les enfants cherchent a se distraire;
```

I would like to use the substr function and  other  method  of  str but  I'm lost.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: The last line is it ", les enfants" or "; les enfants"? if you simply need to split string by a char ';' then look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/249120